# Passing table row to JS file

Tags: jquery, repeater, onchange

I am trying to pass not only the dropdownlist ID using this, but I'm also trying to pass the row.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownPhase" _clientId="comboboxPhase" runat="server" Font-Size="xx-small" onchange="SummaryHelper.onPhaseChange(this,this.tr);" />
```

Here is the Javascript from my JS File

```
onPhaseChange: function(dropdown, row) {
    var combobox = $(dropdown);
    var table = combobox.parents("table").eq(0);
    comboboxWorkUnit = row.find("select.workUnit");

    if (combobox.data('oldValue') || !combobox.find("option[value='']").length) {
        comboboxWorkUnit.hide();
    }

},
```

When I run it the way it is I get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `this.tr` is nothing. I'd be curious to know where you got that.

If you want to pass the row, you'll need to get the row just like you are in the function.

```
onchange="SummaryHelper.onPhaseChange(this,$(this).closest('tr'));"
```

This passes a jQuery object with the row since you're using it like a jQuery object in the function.

---

But then you could just do it in the function too.

```
onPhaseChange: function(dropdown) {
    var combobox = $(dropdown);
    var row = combobox.closest('tr');
    var table = combobox.parents("table").eq(0);
    comboboxWorkUnit = row.find("select.workUnit");

    if (combobox.data('oldValue') || !combobox.find("option[value='']").length) {
        comboboxWorkUnit.hide();
    }

},
```

Comment: i actually made up this.tr figured it was worth a try.

Thanks for the help it worked great.

i think doing it in the function itself is actually better thanks

Comment: this is a little off topic but for some reason if i do comboboxworkunit.hide() it works but when i try to use .show() it doesnt work

Comment: @bugz: Not sure why that would be. Check your browser's developer console to see if there are any errors.